# Streaming REST API on Google AppEngine with python

Tags: python, rest, google-app-engine, nest-api

I'm trying to call the Nest REST Streaming API on Google App Engine using python. https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/rest-streaming-guide

Normal REST APIs are not a problem but I'd like to send "push" notifications to user based on some changes happened on Nest devices...

Nest API uses firebase, and it's possibile to use the Streaming REST API in order to listen to changes on APIs datas; unfortunally firebase-python library is not supported on Google App Engine due to some multiprocessing missing feature
https://github.com/ozgur/python-firebase/issues/38

I cannot find some working example on use python-requests in order to consume a Streaming REST API, except for tweepy, https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/streaming.py a twitter library for python that should work on App Engine.
Tweepy uses also the Streaming REST API from twitter. I tried to follow tweepy example, but without success; I always receive a DeadLineException.

What is the right way to implement a Stream REST API client on Google AppEngine? There are some simple working samples?

Comment: It can't work on appengine for a number of reasons. The first being it is a request based architecture with a limit of 60 sec's for front facing requestes. And tasks are limited to 10mins.  You can do it using a managed VM.

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but the [Channel API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/) provides some of the functionality of streaming updates that you are looking for.

Comment: Also, when using a manual or basic scaling instance type for your module, tasks can run up to [24 hours at a time](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#scaling_types).